# Convert .py files to correct encoding for Python 3

Tags: python, encoding, emacs

I just pulled from a git repo where the users are on Python 2. My system is running Python 3 and with no changes in the code, I am getting this error:

```
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

It appears that the solution is to change the char set encoding of the `.py` files, but working in emacs, I'm not clear how to do this. I'm seeing these instructions:

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ChangingEncodings

but I don't understand how to apply these for utf-8. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Emacs use UTF-8 with Python Interactive Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888406/make-emacs-use-utf-8-with-python-interactive-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exists a command `untabify`:

Convert all tabs in region to multiple spaces, preserving columns.
If called interactively with prefix ARG, convert for the entire
buffer.

I.e. call it with C-u to convert all TABs in buffer.

As comment points out correctly: `tabify` does the inverse, converts multiple spaces to tabs - while using spaces seems a common convention not just in Python.

Comment: May want to include the inverse command `tabify` which does the same thing in reverse (converts multiple spaces to tabs).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a python 2/3 issue, it looks like something in that git repo has wrong indentation. The easiest fix would be to replace all tab characters in all the files with spaces using something like sed